# calling -Xbootclasspath/p: from C++

Tags: java, c++

I am trying to programmatically launch a java application on the command line from C++. Everything works until I attempt to prepend some jars to the target application classpath using the "Xbootclasspath/p:" switch. When I do this the Java VM fails to start and generates a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Whats strange is when I print out the -Xbootclasspath string from the C++ program (using cout <<) and then manually copy and paste it into the command line, everything runs as expected. I'm just wondering if the C++ "system" command is implicitly modifying the string in some way before executing it perhaps? Here is the simple C++ code I'm using to launch the Java application:

```
string  generateBootClassPath(){


string bootClassPath = "-Xbootclasspath/p:" + getHomePath() + "\\HyperSpaceClient\\Boot\\BootCompanion.jar;Scale_HyperSpaceClient_DUI\\dist\\Scale_HyperSpaceClient_DUI.jar ";

return bootClassPath;
```

}

Note: the "getHomePath" function above simply returns the current users home directory which is
used as a prefix to where the target "BootCompanion.jar" is always stored.


Then the main function..
here I simply concatenate the java application to load (that was passed in as an argument to 
the main method) with the bootclasspath string I generate above. Then I call into the standard C++ system()
function to pass the string to the command line and execute it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

{

```
string fullStartUpString = java +  generateBootClassPath() + argv[1];

system(fullStartUpString.c_str());
```

}

All pretty standard stuff, not sure why its not working as expected.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 for desktop if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of testing and debugging I managed to resolve the problem in the code example I posted earlier; I thought I'd share the details here in the hope that it may save someone a considerable amount of time and effort should they encounter this problem at some point:

The main issue with the posted code was that the Double Quote character (i.e "), which incidentally is used extensively throughout the posted code sample, is in-fact considered to be a special character by the C++ compiler and as such should, in all but a few cases, be ESCAPED when used as part of a String Literal value that will ultimately be passed to the "system()" command.

**To clarify: system("hello world!"); SHOULD BE WRITTEN AS: system("\"Hello World\"");**

Notice the "\" escape characters preceding each double quote character. Once I made this alteration to the relevant parts of the code sample it worked as expected.